# Whats the correct structure and way to load libraries / packages?

Tags: package, package-development, load

I have create a quite large emacs package now its split over many files.

currently i am running an org block with multiple load calls to load them, this is not idea for redistribution.

How should I setup my project so loading the core file loads all other files ?

> ~/.emacs/folder/core.el
>
> ~/.emacs/folder/main.el

Currently i have a structure like the above, i have placed require calls in main.el but these do not find or load my files, seems it should invoke a load if not available this could be due to require not looking in the current folder ?

Any advice on how to setup this structure so that:

> A I can load main.el should i use load or load library
>
> B how to load the files that main.el requires.

Needed to add to load path with the below commands, then all files load via require correctly, thanks to tylor below.

```
  (add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs/dc/")
  (load "dc-popups")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way to bundle elisp code for redistribution to Emacs users is via package.el, which is described in the [elisp manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Packaging.html). This information is available from within emacs as well, `C-h i m elisp <RET> m packaging <RET>`.

Start there, and if you have specific questions about that process open a new question here.

For the particular issue you note, where `require` fails to load the additional files, you should check that `~/.emacs/folder/` is in the load-path. Otherwise, we need more info (i.e., actual code) to debug your problem.

Comment: I had read at least some of that guide, I missed the part about adding in a folder to my path, this i guess will not be needed when installed from melpa, but for testing it is, added to question for others reference.